# Using onClick to download a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm learning to make my first google chrome extension. There's a website that has a variable titled songPath. I want to create a new button on the screen that when selected will download the url string inside songPath, instead of just opening it and playing it in the browser.

```
<div class="player">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var songPath = "http://songurl.mp3";
    </script>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me to some script code or sample that does something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's "content scripts" have access to the DOM but not the JavaScript environment on the page. But you can do it by injecting a script tag that references your script.

Some good examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/989516